# MagicalRecord - ManyToMany: Do I need to add entities on both sides of the relationship?

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

Let's say you have a many to many relationship between two entities and you use MagicalRecord to manually tie them together.

IE: A `Vet` has many `Pets` and a `Pet` has many `Pets`

In the code, do you need to add the entity on both sides of the relationship;

ie:

```
[vet1 addPetObject:cust1Pet1];
[vet1 addPetObject:cust1Pet2];
[vet1 addPetObject:cust1Pet3];
[cust1Pet1 addVetObject:vet1];
[cust1Pet2 addVetObject:vet1];
```

So, do I need to add the pet object to the vet, and then add the vet to the relevant pet object -- or will Core data / Magical record handle this relationship and tie them on both sides by itself?

Many thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, this functionality is built into Core Data. Magical Record simply provides some easier access to the lower level Core Data functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relationships are defined as *inverse relationships* of each other in the Core Data
model inspector then you need only set one of them. Core Data will automatically update
the inverse relationship. (This is in fact unrelated to MagicalRecord.)